# App se cierra al salir y volver a entrar al Fragment que me muestra la Geolocalización de Google Maps

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Se me cierra la app cuando abro muy seguido el fragment que contiene el mapa de google maps y me genera el siguiente error en el logcat

```
Process: com.example.matia.tonum, PID: 11224
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
        at android.location.GeocoderParams.<init>(GeocoderParams.java:50)
        at android.location.Geocoder.<init>(Geocoder.java:83)
        at com.example.matia.tonum.Fragment.GeoFragment.setLocation(GeoFragment.java:84)
        at com.example.matia.tonum.Fragment.GeoFragment$1.onLocationChanged(GeoFragment.java:127)
        at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport._handleMessage(LocationManager.java:281)
        at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport.access$000(LocationManager.java:210)
        at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport$1.handleMessage(LocationManager.java:226)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5258)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:898)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
```

Y este es el código de mi fragment

```
public class GeoFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private SupportMapFragment mapFragment;
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private Marker marcador;
    double lat = 0.0;
    double lng = 0.0;
    String mensaje1;
    String direccion = "";

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View vista = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_geo, container, false);

        if (mapFragment == null) {
            mapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        }

        getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.map, mapFragment).commit();

        return vista;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        miUbicacion();
    }

    //activar los servicios del gps cuando esten apagados
    public void locationStart() {
        LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        final boolean gpsEnabled = mlocManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        if (!gpsEnabled) {
            Intent settingsIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            startActivity(settingsIntent);
        }

    }

    public void setLocation(Location loc) {
        //Obtener la direccion de la calle a partir de la latitud y la longitud
        if (loc.getLatitude() != 0.0 && loc.getLongitude() != 0.0) {
            try {
                Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getActivity(), Locale.getDefault());
                List<Address> list = geocoder.getFromLocation(
                        loc.getLatitude(), loc.getLongitude(), 1);
                if (!list.isEmpty()) {
                    Address DirCalle = list.get(0);
                    direccion = (DirCalle.getAddressLine(0));
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    //agregar el marcador en el mapa
    private void AgregarMarcador(double lat, double lng) {
        LatLng coordenadas = new LatLng(lat, lng);
        CameraUpdate MiUbicacion = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(coordenadas, 16);
        if (marcador != null) marcador.remove();
        marcador = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(coordenadas)
                .title("Dirección: " + direccion)
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)));
        mMap.animateCamera(MiUbicacion);
    }

    //actualizar la ubicacion
    private void ActualizarUbicacion(Location location) {
        if (location != null) {
            lat = location.getLatitude();
            lng = location.getLongitude();
            AgregarMarcador(lat, lng);

        }
    }

    //control del gps
    LocationListener locListener = new LocationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

            ActualizarUbicacion(location);
            setLocation(location);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {
            mensaje1 = ("GPS Activado");
            Mensaje();
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
            mensaje1 = ("GPS Desactivado");
            locationStart();
            Mensaje();
        }
    };
    private static int PETICION_PERMISO_LOCALIZACION = 101;

    private void miUbicacion() {

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission
                (getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    PETICION_PERMISO_LOCALIZACION);
            return;
        } else {
            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            ActualizarUbicacion(location);
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,1200,0,locListener);
        }

    }

    public void Mensaje() {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), mensaje1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        //toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
        toast.show();
    }

}
```

Esto es parte de la linea 84, desde el trycatch es la linea 84:

```
public void setLocation(Location loc) {
        //Obtener la direccion de la calle a partir de la latitud y la longitud
        if (loc.getLatitude() != 0.0 && loc.getLongitude() != 0.0) {
            try {
                Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getActivity(), Locale.getDefault());
                List<Address> list = geocoder.getFromLocation(
                        loc.getLatitude(), loc.getLongitude(), 1);
                if (!list.isEmpty()) {
                    Address DirCalle = list.get(0);
                    direccion = (DirCalle.getAddressLine(0));
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Espero puedan ayudarme...

Desde ya, muchas gracias por todo!

Comment: ¿Cual es la linea 84 de  GeoFragment.java ?

Comment: Lo agregue arriba @Jorgesys, la linea 84 empieza en el trycatch

Comment: Cambia getActivity() por getContext() : Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getContext(), Locale.getDefault());

Comment: Me sigue dando el mismo error con el getContext(), no sé cuál será el problema. Surge cada vez que cambio de Fragment y vuelvo a entrar al Fragment de Google Maps

Comment: Prueba inicializar tu `Geocoder` en el `onCreateView ` y después lo utilizas en tu método.

Answer (score 1):

Veo que desde tu `LocationListener` estas llamando a `setLocation()` y en ese momento tu método no tiene referencia al `context`, lo que puedes hacer es pasarlo como parámetro directamente en el método o pasarlo mediante el constructor del listener:

```
setLocation(context, location);
```

- minSDK <= 21, usa getActivity().
- minSDK >=23, usa getContext().

Comment: Ya le sugerí usar getContext(). pero comenta que el error persiste.

Comment: Sí chicos, pero ya solucione el problema, ahora no estoy en el computador por eso no he comentado. Muchas gracias por todo!